# Integer input validation

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java and I'd like to know if there's any way to improve or refactor the prompt on validating integer values for best practices.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a, b, c;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  // Prompt for a
  System.out.print("a: ");
  if (!in.hasNextInt() || (a = in.nextInt()) <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Input must be a positive integer!");
   return;
  }
  
  // Prompt for b
  System.out.print("b: ");
  if (!in.hasNextInt() || (b = in.nextInt()) <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Input must be a positive integer!");
   return;
  }
  
  // Prompt for c
  System.out.print("c: ");
  if (!in.hasNextInt() || (c = in.nextInt()) <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Input must be a positive integer!");
   return;
  }
  
  if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) {
   System.out.println("It's a traingle.");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Invalid lengths for a traingle.");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Code Repetition**

In your program, you are using the following code three times:

```
System.out.print("a: ");
if (!in.hasNextInt() || (a = in.nextInt()) <= 0) {
 System.out.println("Input must be a positive integer!");
 return;
}
```

You should use a method for this:

```
public static int getUserInput() {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int number;
 if (!in.hasNextInt() || (number = in.nextInt()) <= 0) {
  System.out.println("Input must be a positive integer!");
  return -1; //Returns -1 for illegal input
 }
 return number;
}
```

---

**Input validation**

It's good that you control, whether the user made a valid input, but this point can be improved further: Your program stops, when the user makes an invalid input. That's not what an user expects:

```
public static int getUserInput(String var) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int number;
 while(true) {
  try {
   System.out.print(var + ": ");
   number = sc.nextInt();
   if(number <= 0) {
    throw new InputMismatchException();
   }
   break;  
  } 
  catch(InputMismatchException e) {
   System.out.println("Enter a number > 0.");
   sc.nextLine();
  }
 } 
 return number;
}
```

By using this code, the user will be able to make inputs until making a valid input. If you don't know about `try-catch` yet, i suggest reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) explanation.

---

**Logic**

I would create a seperate method for the "triangle-validation":

```
public static boolean isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
 if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

---

**Style**

Please consider using more than one space for indentation. My suggestion is two or even four spaces. This improves the legibility.

---

**Final code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, c;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt for a
        a = getUserInput("a");

        // Prompt for b
        b = getUserInput("b");


        // Prompt for c
        c = getUserInput("c");

        if (isTriangle(a, b, c)) {
            System.out.println("It's a triangle.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid lengths for a triangle.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if (a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int getUserInput(String var) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.print(var + ": ");
                number = sc.nextInt();
                if(number <= 0) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                break;  
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number > 0.");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        } 
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not also replace the isTriangle function into a single line?
```public static boolean isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a;
    }```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I tried to keep it simple, because the questioner is "fairly new to java".

Comment: Thank you @PhilippWilhelm ! It is very helpful.

Comment: you could also remove a minor typo: `traingle` vs `triangle` (2x) *gg

Comment: @MartinFrank Done! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: thank you for apprechiating it! (i hope i was not too mean to you!)

Comment: No, you helped me improve my answer. This is something I will always appreciate.